# 「～だら」という一部遠州弁の使い方

Tags: dialects

For my understanding after being told by my friend what is だら means, its like でしょう in common mean but for most of the time my friends said ら to in another expression which I cannot notice. Could you explain to me deeper of how to use だら in another form?

Comment: FYI: http://www.kisoya.net/bunpou.htm

Comment: That what I looking for, thank you